# not mandatory date_column model validation for invalid date assignment 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, date, model

consider scenario,

`User model with name, birth_date fields` (here birth_date is optional)

inside view form birth_date is assigned as '31/31/1985' which is invalid

ideally user object should be invalid and raise and error on birth_date field but thats not happening and user object gets saved with birth_date as blank which is completely misleading.

After debugging found that while assigning attributes birth_date value it gets assigned as blank and as birth_date is optional object gets saved.

```
u = User.new
# invalid date assignment
u.birth_date = '31/31/2011'
u.birth_date #=> nil
# valid date assignment
u.birth_date = '1/1/2011'
u.birth_date #=> Sat, 01 Jan 2011

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(args={})
    logger.info args[:birth_date] #invalid value comes upto here but vanishes afterwords
    super
  end
end
```

I am not saying its incorrect, but it should not misleading from user point of view.
bcz after entering invalid birth_date user will assume he entered correct birth_date but actually his birth_date is not saved at all.

Any clue how to get around this issue ??

Comment: Do you have any validations set up? Can you add them

Comment: i do have validations on other fields such as name, joining_date presence and there are working proper. my concern is only on not mandatory date field validation on invalid assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether the `allow_blank` and `allow_nil` options work with custom validations, but it's easy to write it yourself.

```
validate :valid_birth_date

private
  def valid_birth_date
    errors.add(:birth_date, "is invalid.") unless birth_date.blank? || valid_date?(birth_date)
  end

  def valid_date?(date)
    begin
      !!Date.parse(date)
    rescue
      false
    end
  end
```

Comment: custom validation above seems to be ok ..but you haven't noticed actual problem with invalid date assignment. birth_date gets blank after invalid assignment and hence no use.
`user.birth_date = '31/31/2011'`
`user.birth_date #=> nil`
`user.valid? #=> true`

Comment: Are you getting those results with the validations from above? That shouldn't happen. Are you doing anything else with the birth_date? Do you have it said as attr_accessible?

Comment: these results are getting displayed before validation. it has nothing to do with validations.
It looks like the smart way could be 'restrict user from entering invalid date'